# Guardar una colección de datos de Eloquent en un archivo .json en laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, json, eloquent, controller

```
Modelo: User
Controlador: UserController
Archivo: userlist.json
```

**UserController**

```
public function index()
    {
        
        $users = User::all('name', 'email', 'gender', 'username');            

        return Response::json(
            array('success'=>true, 'users' => $users), 200
        );
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto me genera un .json con los resultados de $users como la imagen anterior, el cual puedo visualizar en la vista que me genera index(). Ahora bien, lo que yo necesito es guardar este resultado obtenido en el archivo "resources/data/userlist.json". Quisiera me ayudaran por favor.

Comment: puedes guardarlo con Storage pero te lo guardara en la carpeta public, `Storage::disk('public')->put('userlist.json', $users);`

Answer (score 0):

primero deberas modificar filesystems.php y en el arreglo `disk` agregar:

```
'resources' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path('/resources/data'), 
    ],
```

en la parte de root el `base_path('/resources/data')` es el directorio que quieres guardar los archivos esto seria como `C:\Users\YoUser\otraCarpeta\Carpeta_de_laravel\resources\data` con esto ya puedes guardar desde tu controlador con Storage:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all('name', 'email', 'gender', 'username');
    $collectionUsers = collect(['users' => $users]);
    Storage::disk('resource')->put('userlist.json', $collectionUsers);
    return Response::json(
        array('success' => true, 'users' => $users),
        200
    );
}
```

cree un collection para agregar el key `users` y que lo guardara.